# Class methods on all search result using Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a model `Item` which has many tags (using acts-as-taggable-on)

Using sunspot, I search for items like so:

```
@search = Item.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
  paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 20
end
```

This works fine but, for the items returned from the search, I want to also be able to show a list of unique tags with a count of occurrences of each tag.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
@serch.results.tag_counts
```

(`tag_counts` is a class method of `Item` added by acts-as-taggable-on)

This would work fine if this was an ActiveRecord query, but obviously my search results have the class `Sunspot::Search::PaginatedCollection` rather than `Item` or `ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Item` - which means my class methods are not accessible.

Even if I did have access to the `tag_counts` class method, this would only return the results for my paginated collection - it would only work for the first 20 items.

Any ideas about how to achieve this for all matching search results?

Comment: From what I understand, I think you want to do a faceted search. There is the `facet` option for sunspot. Have a look at the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement such a functionality you should use a "facet".

In sunspot this looks something like this:

```
Post.search do
  [...]
  facet :category_ids, :author_id
end
```